# how I can use Global.asax and implement handler for it?

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

I have a Global.ascx and I wrote a simple url writer module :

> ```
> void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     try
>     {
>         string strPath = Context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
>         string[] sections = strPath.Split('/');
>         int len = sections.Length;
>         string strExtention = sections[len - 1].Split('.')[1];
>         if (strExtention.ToLower().TrimEnd().Equals("xml"))
>         {
>             if (sections[len - 2].Equals("ATM"))
>                 Context.RewritePath("~/Include/XML Files/Orders/TMP/" + sections[len - 1]);
>             else
>                 Context.RewritePath("~/Include/XML Files/Orders/" + sections[len - 1]);
>         }
>     }
>     catch
>     {
>     }
> }
> ```

it works locally but it dosen't work in the host how I can implement handler for this ?

Server.Transfer doesn't work also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct with going down the route of a module.  However instead of  `Context.RewritePath()` use `Response.Redirect()`, this simply returns a 3xx message to the browser which will redirect its request to the new URL.  This should work wherever it's implemented.

Comment: but if I use redirect instead of rewrite everyone will find out easily my original path and I don't like it

Comment: In that case use `Server.Tranfer()` this will transfer execution to another page (keeping the old URL showing) however I'm not sure how this will react in terms of a module

Comment: Try offering a bounty for the question, as if this doesn't work I do not know the answer